# Algorithm parameter keys of MOEA framework

Tags: java, algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Using the `withProperty` method of the executing routine you can set several parameters of an algorithm i.e. for `NSGA-II`

```
NondominatedPopulation result = new Executor()
  .withProblem("UF1")
  .withAlgorithm("NSGAII")
  .withMaxEvaluations(10000)
  .withProperty("populationSize", 50)
  .withProperty("sbx.rate", 0.9)
  .withProperty("sbx.distributionIndex", 15.0)
  .run();
```

The documentation says

> Each algorithm deﬁnes its own parameters. Refer to the API documentation 
>       for the exact parameter keys. Any parameters not explicitly deﬁned using
>       the withProperty methods will be set to their default values.

But I can not find these keys within `NSGAII` class. Can you give me a link to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found them here: http://www.moeaframework.org/javadoc/org/moeaframework/algorithm/jmetal/JMetalAlgorithms.html

Man, those are not easy to find!

Your algorithm (NSGAII) in particular uses:  NSGAII -> populationSize, maxEvaluations

Also ... totally agree that the NSGAII API documentation would've been a *great* place to put this information.

Comment: Thanks for a great job! Well, I just see the documentation also contains in chapter 9 the description of all algorithms with their parameters. But you are right it is really confusing...